# System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode c# using

Tags: c#, urlencode

In the following code:

```
for (int line = 0; line < CHUNKSTOBEFOUND; line++) {
    nvc.Add ("search", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode (stringsToSearchFor[line]));
}
```

I get told namespace name HttpUtility does not exist. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx seems to indicate I should use System.Web. I've tried using that, but I STILL get the error. Is there something else I'm supposed to include or use?

Answer (score 2):

As competent_said, you are probably targeting the `Client Profile` in your project, in which System.Web.dll is not available. You can [target the full framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Project Properties to get it back working.

Another possible cause could be that you are not referencing `System.Web` library. To do so:

1. Right click the "Reference" in the Solution Explorer.
2. Choose "Add Reference"
3. Check the ".NET" tab is selected.
4. Search for, and add "System.Web".

Maybe you are just missing an using directive `using System.Web;` on the top of your source file.

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you! I needed to do both as it turns out!

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using the [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) version of the .Net framework. You need to open your project properties and [change the framework version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the full version.